# Why is an init method of a child not called by a parent allocating that child in cocos2d v2.0?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have this Class:

```
//Interface
@interface SavingDataPlist : SimpleTimedGameRecipe
{   
    NSMutableArray *moles;
    int tagCount;
    int moleCount;
    CCSprite *mallet;
    CGPoint malletPosition;
}

-(CCLayer*) runRecipe;
-(void) step;
-(void) initBackground;
-(void) createMoleAtPosition:(CGPoint)point withZ:(float)z;
-(void) processMoleHit;

-(void) addHiScoresToMenu;
-(void) loadHiScores;
-(void) addHiScore;
-(void) deleteHiScores;
-(void) startNewGame;
-(void) gameOver;
-(void) step:(ccTime)delta;
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

which in its reunRecipe method calls this:

```
[self createMoleAtPosition:ccp(50,205) withZ:0];
```

and that call corresponds to this method:

```
-(void) createMoleAtPosition:(CGPoint)point withZ:(float)z {
    CCSpriteFrameCache *cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

    CCSprite *back = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"mole_back.png"]];
    back.position = ccp(point.x, point.y);
    [self addChild:back z:z tag:tagCount];
    tagCount++;

    Mole *mole = [Mole spriteWithSpriteFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"mole_normal.png"]];
    [mole setDownPosition:ccp(point.x,point.y-30)];
    [self addChild:mole z:z tag:tagCount];
    [moles addObject:mole];
    NSLog(@"moles.count %d", moles.count);
    tagCount++;

    CCSprite *front = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"mole_front.png"]];
    front.position = ccp(point.x, point.y);
    [self addChild:front z:z tag:tagCount];
    tagCount++;

}
```

The Mole Class init method looks like this:

```
-(id)init {
    NSLog(@"moleinit");

    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        state = MOLE_DOWN;

        CCSpriteFrameCache *cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

        //
        //MEVPCHANGE
        //Create framenumber array to populate ccanimation later
        NSMutableArray *animationFramesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *animationFramesArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        //MEVPCHANGE - add frames to array
        [animationFramesArray addObject:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"mole_normal.png"]];
        [animationFramesArray2 addObject:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"mole_hit.png"]];

        normalAnim = [[CCAnimation alloc] initWithSpriteFrames:animationFramesArray delay:1.0f];
        hitAnim = [[CCAnimation alloc] initWithSpriteFrames:animationFramesArray2 delay:1.0f];

        //MEVPCHANGE - create animation
        [animationFramesArray release];
        [animationFramesArray2 release];

        //


        [self runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:normalAnim]]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Now in cocos2d v1.0 this code works fine.  The Mole's get created and they pop up and down when they get whacked.  But in v2.0, I only get the front facing moles but the NSLog in the Mole init method doesnt even get called (as evidenced by the lack of NSLog in the console).

Comment: Mole *mole = [Mole spriteWithSpriteFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"mole_normal.png"]] what this method does?

Comment: It calls the Mole's init method, at least in the cocos2d v1.  The init method is posted above as the Mole Class init method.  But in cocos2d v2 it never gets called.  Everything else was untouched.

Comment: I just noticed that if i replace the Mole call with ` Mole *mole = [[Mole alloc] init];` it works fine.